# [Actionscript]How to display the information inside an array of objects

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm currently trying to work on a mod for a game and when I display the array all I see is [object Object]. I'm wanting to actually see the information inside of the array. I'm new to actionscript so I feel as if it's probably a simple issue that I'm overlooking.

I've tried everything below. I'm expecting it to return the actual stored information, ex: ids, item name, etc.

```
if(param1.keyCode == 89)
{
    GlobalFunc.SetText(this.debugMenu,String(this.m_TheirOffersData[0].toString()),false);
    GlobalFunc.PlayMenuSound(GlobalFunc.MENU_SOUND_OK);
}
if(param1.keyCode == 85)
{
    for(var id in this.m_TheirOffersData)
    {
        var value:Object = this.m_TheirOffersData[id];
        GlobalFunc.SetText(this.debugMenu,this.trProgress = this.trProgress + trace(id + " = " + value),false);
    }
    GlobalFunc.PlayMenuSound(GlobalFunc.MENU_SOUND_OK);
}
```

Comment: Enumerating dynamic properties in AS3 Objects is not simple. You would likely need to do some serious wok to enumerate stuff, an example is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407713/enumerate-the-properties-of-an-as3-object-that-may-or-may-not-be-dynamic

Comment: LOL tried to change title to "How to display the information inside an Object" - BAM collision with a question for Java. While algorithms would probably be the same - find dynamic properties list, traverse it and parse values, the tools differ. BTW a hint would be to use as3corelib JSON encoder for your task, it already does the job of transforming a custom Object into a human-readable string.

Comment: I actually am looking at that function. I've tried so many different things and it's driving me absolutely crazy. I've been messing with AS for like 3 days and it's a nightmare compared to other languages to me.

Comment: If it is a generic object (a.k.a associative array of key=value pairs) then the simplest way to convert it to text is https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#stringify()